# About a classic result from Han and Lin's PDE book

Tags: elliptic-pde, regularity

Let $A=a_{ij}$ be an $n \times n $ a symmetric matrix where the coeficients are in $L^{\infty}(B_r(0))$ and satisfies

$$ \lambda |\xi|^2 \leq a_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j \leq \alpha |\xi|^2, \  x \in B_r(0), \xi \in R^n$$

for some positive constants $\lambda $ and $\alpha$ with $0<\lambda < \alpha$.

Consider the well know result from regularity theory of elliptic equations (the result can be found for example in the classic PDE book of Han and Lin):

> **Theorem**: Let $u \in H^1(B_r(0)) $   satisfying 
>   $$ \int_{B_r(0)} a_{ij}D_i u D_j\varphi = 0, \forall \varphi \in  H^1_0(B_r(0)),$$
>   and consider the above matrix.
>
> Then there exists $\beta \in (0,1)$ such that for any $\rho < r$
>   $$ \int_{B_{\rho}(0)} |Du|^2 \leq  C\left(\frac{\rho}{r}\right)^{n-2 + 2 \beta} \int_{B_{r}(0)} |Du|^2 $$
>   where $C$ is a positive constant that depends only on $n$ and $\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$.

**My question is**: Is there a similar result where $\beta$ does not appear if I suppose that the coefficients of the matrix are Lipschtz functions?

I searched in the books and articles of Giaquinta and Giusti, but I did not find anything that helps me in the direction of my question.
About a week ago I asked the question below in math.stackexchange and I did not obtain answers; I think this site should be more suitable for this question.

Thanks in advance!